# Regular Expression working in Firefox but not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using a regex that should allow only numbers, alphabets, comma, underscore and hyphen:

```
var test = "ABCD_3_8.csv";
var checkFileNameValidity = false;

try {
    var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/g;
    var match;
    while (match = re.exec(test)) {
        var resultText = match[1] || match[2];
        checkFileNameValidity = true;
    }
} catch (e) {
    alert(e);
}

if (checkFileNameValidity == false) {
    alert("Invalid File Name");
    return;
}
```

This code works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome. Why's that, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't work any where as you have this regex:

```
var re = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$/g; // same as /^[\w.-]+$/g
```

And then you're using 2 captured groups in `var resultText = match[1] || match[2];`

even though you have none in your regex.

Comment: Just explain what you are trying with `resultText = match[1] || match[2]`